# Launch Existing UIViewController from React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to add new functionality to an existing IOS app using react native. I plan to build the new screen with React but I also need to be able to launch out to an ViewController (I don't want to rewrite it in react just yet).

So far I have:
- Added RCTRootView to a UINavigationController
- Created a React Native Module that enables me to posts a NSNotification to signal a UIViewController needs to be pushed
- Wired up the UINavigationController to receive a notification and push a UIViewController

All this works but there is one issue, I am experiencing a significant delay for the UI to draw. I step through the code, every thing executes fine but the screen doesn't update for 10-15 seconds.

I have done another test with a simple UIAlertView instead of trying to push a UIViewController, same issue. Is there some sort of event loop issue when trying to get react to pass back control to native app?

Comment: Try to push your code like this    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [theNavi pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    });